# How to maximize amount of NestJS/NodeJS requests to another server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs, ddos

I want to make a service (for training purposes) for throwing a resource of some kind with a large number of requests, like this: GET example.com/someResource

I tried this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  this.http.get('example.com/someResource').toPromise();
  // that's a NestJS so it's a HttpService of HttpModule (Obvservable, so we need to transform it to Promise using 'toPromise()')
}
```

But this does not seem to work, because the requests take too long and a small ratio of time/number of requests is obtained (in 4 seconds only 500 requests, at the same time on python about 1200 requests per second can be squeezed out) How can we improve this and send more requests? Help, please, the course is on))

Comment: Well, this might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53964228/how-do-i-perform-a-large-batch-of-promises

Comment: i dunno how to mark your comment as a resolve, buuuuut
THANK YOOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64105561/processing-a-lot-of-requests-without-crashing/64106288#64106288